# Найти наибольшую возрастающую подпоследовательность с 1 разрывом

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Необходимо из заданной числовой последовательности A длины n, вычеркнуть минимальное число элементов, чтобы оставшиеся элементы образовали строго возрастающую почти всюду подпоследовательность, т. е. содержащую не более одного разрыва — пары (ai, ai + 1) подряд идущих элементов, второй из которых не больше первого. Построенный алгоритм должен иметь трудоёмкость O(n log n). 
В выходной файл вывести длину наибольшей последовательности.
Вот мой код,но я тут не учитываю достаточно много вариантов,как оказалось. Подскажите,пожалуйста,алгоритм решения

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int const INF=2000000000;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");

    int n;
    fin>>n;
    vector<int>A;
    int i;
    int N=0;
    while(fin>>i)
    {
        A.push_back(i);
        N++;
    }
    vector<int>d(N);
    d[0] = -INF;
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        d[i]=INF;
    }
    int len;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        int j = int (upper_bound (d.begin(), d.end(), A[i]) - d.begin());
        if (d[j-1] < A[i] && A[i] < d[j])
        {
            d[j] = A[i];
            len=j;
        }
    }
    if(len==n)
    {
        fout<<len;
    }
    else
        fout<<len+1;




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Разобьём решение задачи на два этапа.

**1. Нахождение наидлиннейшей возрастающей подпоследовательности.**

По мотивам: [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log) .

Пусть n - длина последовательности a_0, ... , a_n.

Задача решается динамическим программированием, заполняется массив int d[n + 1], d[k] = длина наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности, оканчивающейся строго в a_k; .

Формула динамики:

[image: Формула динамики]

Асимптотика такого алгоритма получается равной O(n^2), один n это пробег по d , второй n это пробег от 0 до k для подсчёта очередного значения d[k] (в формуле).

Этот алгоритм можно оптимизировать до O(nlogn), используя двоичный поиск. Так как d[k - 1] < d[k], и каждый элемент последовательности a_i обновляет не более одной ячейки d, то при применении формулы выше достаточно двоичным поиском найти первое число, которое строго больше a_i, и обновить соответствующий элемент по формуле выше.

Реализация:

```
std::vector<int> d(MAXN);
d[0] = -INF;
for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    d[i] = INF;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int j = int (std::upper_bound (d.begin(), d.end(), a[i]) - d.begin());
    if (d[j-1] < a[i] && a[i] < d[j])
        d[j] = a[i];
}
```

Асимптотика последней реализации O(nlogn), что нам подходит.

Ответом является значение последнего элемента массива d;

**2. Поиск двух наибольших подпоследовательностей.**

Аналогично пункту (1) можно найти наибольшую убывающую подпоследовательность, только искать её будем для инвертированной последовательности b_i = a_{n - i}. Заполним таким образом два массива d1[n+1] и d2[n+2]. Тогда у нас будет в d1[k] длина наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности, **оканчивающейся** в позиции k, а в d2[k] длина наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности, **начинающейся** в позиции k. Построить два таких массива мы можем за O(nlogn), затем одним пробегом находим максимум суммы d1[k] + d2[k] , соответствующее k это и будет место разрыва, сумма - длина наибольшей подпоследовательности с одним разрывом.

Итоговая сложность: O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n) = O(nlogn), как и требовалось.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сейчас реализовать . Откуда вы узнали этот алгоритм, может посоветуете литературу? Потому что первую часть я реализовал в задаче, но вторую нет

Comment: Первый пункт это с емакса, там ссылка есть выше (оттуда ответ и списал на самом деле). Второй - сам придумал, он несложно придумывается :) А по литературе - Кормен, Алгоритмы: Построение и анализ , наверное, это одна из лучших книг об алгоритмах в общем.

Comment: Только вот одна неувязочка. В 1 пункте вы говорите, что d хранит в себе длину наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности оканчевающейся строго в k, но согласно приведённом коду получается, что в d мы храним элемент из последовательности, а не длину

Comment: Задача решена,только Вы слегка не так её объяснили её реализацию и собственно код. Но сама идея великолепна,огромное спасибо. Если кого-то заинтересовала эта задача,то пишите,помогу с радостью

Comment: Рад был помочь. Думаю, будет неплохо, если вы напишете исправленный кусок кода для пункта 1 (у меня действительно там косяк, я его скопировал с емакса, не посмотрев, что в нём). Для тех, кто в будущем будет читать этот вопрос и ответ, ваше дополнение будет очень полезным.

Comment: да,доработаю ваш код