# Нахождение возрастающей и убывающей последовательности

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Есть вот такая задача:
Группа альпинистов покорила много вершин и возвратилась в родной город. Одна из местных газет решила написать статью об их походе. Как выяснилось, в процессе похода альпинисты n раз останавливались на ночлег на той или иной высоте. Поскольку главный редактор газеты настаивает, чтобы название статьи было «Восхождение и спуск», решено было не упоминать о некоторых днях похода, рассказав лишь о восхождении, причем если статья будет рассказывать о x1-м, x2-м, …, x2k + 1-м днях (x1 < x2 < … < x2k + 1), то должно выполняться условие

hx1 < hx2 < … < hxk < hxk + 1 > hxk + 2 > … > hx2k + 1.
Найдите максимальное k, для которого можно соответствующим образом выбрать 2k + 1 дней.
Пример
Входные данные:
7 дней,
1 3 2 10 7 2 1
Выходные:
число k=2,сами дни:
1 2 5 6 7

Хотелось бы услышать какой-либо алгоритм и хотя бы частично реализацию.
Вот что придумал я сам,если есть умные и полезные мысли,то прошу их отметить и сказать,что я на правильном пути:)
Итак,в первую очередь я бы находил наибольшую возрастающую подпоследовательность. Такой алгоритм я вроде бы умею реализовывать. На следующем шаге я хочу находить наибольшую убывающую подпоследовательность. При этом во время вот этих всех нахождениях,я по индексу каждого элемента последовательности писал бы размер подпоследовательности,которая строго оканчивается в данном месте. И в итоге получается,что я могу пройти циклом по массивам в котором писал информацию о длине возрастающей подпоследовательности оканчивающейся в данном элементе и об убывающей оканчивающейся в данном. И наибольшая сумма по данному индексу в двух массивах и есть ответ на мою задачу. Но тут уже есть две проблемки. Первая: как я понял из условия,то должно быть нечётное количество элементов,а как тогда мне отбросить чётное количество? А второе: мне же надо в итоге вывести ещё и как бы саму последовательность? а как тогда восстановить результаты? Раз тема у задачи динамическое программирование,то может следует как-то разбить её на подзадачи и записывать в таблицу результаты? Но тут уже я не очень понимаю как это сделать. 
Если я не утомил Вас своей писаниной) то прошу какой-либо помощи,заранее спасибо

хочу добавить код на ++,к сожалению задача так и не решилась,похоже,что алгоритм всё же не верен

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");//report.in
    ofstream fout("output.txt");//report.out

    int n;
    fin >> n;
    vector<int>A;
    vector<int>B(n);
    int i;
    int j = n - 1;
    while (fin >> i)
    {
        A.push_back(i);
        B[j] = i;
        j--;
    }

    vector<int>d1(n);
    vector<int>p1(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        d1[i] = 1;
        p1[i] = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (A[j] < A[i])
                if (1 + d1[j] > d1[i]) {
                    d1[i] = 1 + d1[j];
                    p1[i] = j;
                }
    }
    vector<int>d2(n);
    vector<int>p2(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        d2[i] = 1;
        p2[i] = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (B[j] < B[i])
                if (1 + d2[j] > d2[i]) {
                    d2[i] = 1 + d2[j];
                    p2[i] = j;
                }
    }


    int MAX = 0;
    int ind;
    bool p = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            if (n / 2 == i)
            {
                if (((d1[i] + d2[i]) - 1) % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if (d1[i] + d2[i] - 1 > MAX)
                    {
                        MAX = d1[i] + d2[i] - 1;
                        ind = i;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        if ((d1[i] + d2[i]) % 2 == 1)
        {
            if (d1[i] + d2[i] > MAX)
            {
                MAX = d1[i] + d2[i];
                ind = i;
            }
        }
    }
    fout << (MAX - 1) / 2 << endl;

    int pos = ind;
    if (pos == n / 2)
        pos--;
    vector<int>path1;
    while (pos != -1)
    {
        path1.push_back(pos);
        pos = p1[pos];
    }
    vector<int>path2;
    while (ind != -1)
    {
        path2.push_back(ind);
        ind = p2[ind];
    }

    for (int i = path1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        fout << path1[i] + 1 << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < path2.size(); i++)
        fout << n - path2[i] << " ";




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаю, идея про место встречи LIS и LDS максимальной суммарной длины верная. Про чётное количество  - достаточно не брать один из элементов с более длинной стороны. Про восстановление результатов - так есть же немало описаний алгоритма LIS с восстановлением, даже в вики

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что такое LIS и LDS?

Comment: возрастающая и убывающая подпоследовательности (Longest Increasing/Decreasing Subsequence)

Comment: @Артём , ниже я ответил, а потом заметил, что вопрос, на который я сослался также от вас :) В том вопросе вы без труда разобрались, обратите внимание, что ваш новый вопрос полностью аналогичен, уверен, увидев аналогию (я на неё намекнул ниже) вы разберётесь в новой задаче. Желаю успехов :)

Comment: Да, я же описал свой алгоритм в вопросе и хотел уточнить является ли он правильным и обоснованно. Раз вы это подтверждаете, то буду приступать к написанию кода:)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вопрос, похожий на ваш: [Найти наибольшую возрастающую подпоследовательность с 1 разрывом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886701/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-1-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/). Мне кажется, в нём содержится ответ и на ваш вопрос (вам надо лишь внести небольшое изменение, там ищется наибольшая убывающая последовательность с конца, и наибольшая возрастающая с начала, а вам надо искать наибольшую возрастающую с обоих сторон, ну а дальше всё в точности также, используя два массива от динамики).

PS. Могу конечно скопировать ответ оттуда сюда, внеся необходимые коррективы, но мне кажется, там итак несложно разобраться.

Comment: Хотелось бы снова услышать советы по данной задаче,так как уже совсем отчаялся и никак не могу найти решение